# 'babel-core/register' vs 'babel-register'

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

We can transpile sources on the fly using "babel-register"

https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/

but I am having trouble verifying which one is the one to use:

```
require('babel-core/register')
```

or

```
require('babel-register')
```

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

They are the same. All `babel-core/register` does is `require('babel-register')`. https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/cb8c4172ef740aa562f0873d602d800c55e80c6d/packages/babel-core/register.js#L3

The recommended usage is `babel-register` since that is the module where the code actually lives, and `babel-core/register` has been removed in Babel 7.x. Better to depend specifically on the module you use, rather than load it as a side-effect of `babel-core`.

Comment: `babel-core/register` was [removed](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/v7.0.0-alpha.1/packages/babel-core/register.js) in `babel-7.x`. Please update [the link](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/v6.26.0/packages/babel-core/register.js).

Comment: @babel/register nowdays

Comment: @Hitmands Only if you're willing to opt into beta versions, but yeah it'll be the correct way eventually.